# how many s3 prefix do I have in this structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, prefix

I try to understand the definition of s3 prefix, so for the following structure, how many s3 prefix do I have? I mean the "independent" prefix that I can have 3500 PUT per second.

Are sub folders considered as prefix to benefit the s3 performance?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't "have prefixes". Rather, a Prefix is a way of referring to a subset of a bucket.

These are valid prefixes you might use:

```
folder1/
lambda/
lambda/folder2/
lambda/folder2/folder3/
```

You could even refer to part of a Key in the Prefix:

```
lambda/terraform
```

Think of the `Prefix` as simply saying "The objects with a Key that begins with..."